# Shopify Webhooks Hmac Python verification fails

Tags: python, flask, shopify, hmac, shopify-app

I am trying to verify the webhook received from Shopify but the Hmac verification fails.

```
def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), data, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)
    return hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, hmac_header.encode('utf-8'))


@app.route('/productCreation', methods=['POST'])
def productCreation():
    data = request.data
    verified = verify_webhook(
        data, request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256'))
    
    if(verified):
        return ("Success", 200)
    return("Integrity error", 401)
```

Getting error as

```
hash = hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), body.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Can anyone help with this? I am developing a Flask app for this.

Answer (score 0):

You´re getting a attribute error, means your **body** object is not a string (encode() is working for string like objects) as mentioned in the error message it is a 'bytes' like object. Remove the
`.encode('utf-8')` from **body**.

Answer (score 0):

## Update March 2022

It seems like Shopify has updated their Flask example with the same changes I suggested below.

## Original answer

I got the same error when using [Shopify's Flask example](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https#verify-the-request-is-from-shopify)

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET = 'hush'

def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET, data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

    return hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, hmac_header.encode('utf-8'))

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    data = request.get_data()
    verified = verify_webhook(data, request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256'))

    if not verified:
        abort(401)

    # process webhook payload
    # ...

    return ('', 200)
```

To get it to work I had to modify verify_webhook by:

- Encoding SECRET since [hmac.new()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new) expects the key in bytes and not as a string.
- Not encoding data since Flask's [response.get_data](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.get_data.html#flask-request-get-data) already returns an encoded bytestring.

### The final code

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET = 'hush'

def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), data, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

    return hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, hmac_header.encode('utf-8'))

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    data = request.get_data()
    verified = verify_webhook(data, request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256'))

    if not verified:
        abort(401)

    # process webhook payload
    # ...

    return ('', 200)
```