# Webhook verification fails with Shopify triggering an Azure function

Tags: python, azure-functions, webhooks, hmac, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a webhook consumer:

- Shopify is posting the data
- an Azure function written in Python is triggered by HTTP
- the sample code below just logged the result of the webhook verificationthe result of the verification is being logged

There's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators) by Shopify, but as I'm not using Flask (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69326620/3116231) SO question), I modified the code a bit:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import json

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="webhook-trigger")
@app.route(route="webhook", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def webhook_process(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function is processing a request.')
    verified = verify(req)
    logging.info("Webhook verified: {}".format(verified))
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
            status_code=200
    )

def verify(req: func.HttpRequest) -> bool:
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
    header = req.headers
    data = req.get_json()

    encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(CLIENT_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), encoded_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

    logging.info("computed_hmac: {}".format(computed_hmac))
    logging.info("header['X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256'] encoded: {}".format(header['X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256'].encode('utf-8')))
    
    verified = hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, header['X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256'].encode('utf-8'))

    return verified
```

The logging output:
[image]

I don't understand, why the verification fails (possibly due to some encoding stuff which I did wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
    def verify(req: func.HttpRequest) -> bool:
        # CLIENT_SECRET must be binary!!!
        CLIENT_SECRET = b"xxxxx"
        header = req.headers
        data = req.get_body()
        
        digest = hmac.new(CLIENT_SECRET, data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

        verified = hmac.compare_digest(
            computed_hmac, header["X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256"].encode("utf-8")
        )

        return verified
```